# Getting data from the database before form submitting

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask

I have a database with users. I can get the users `email` from the drop-down list to the modal window. using `ajax`.

**The question is how to receive `born_date` and `phone_number` of this user via his `email` in the same modal window**, and then send the form for processing. Something doesn’t work. What could be the mistake?

DB strcture:

[image]

`python:`

```
description = ['mymail@gmail','mymail@gmail','uuser@mail.ru','mymail2222@gmail','my1212mail@gmail','11mymail@gmail']


@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET'])
def profile():
    if request.method == 'GET' and 'loggedin' in session:
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM users.data WHERE description = 'description'")
        account = cur.fetchall()
        description = account
        return render_template('profile.html', id=session['id'], email=session['email'],
                                                firstname=session['firstname'], description=description)


@app.route('/profile', methods=['POST'])
def profile_post():
    data = request.json
    data_list = list(data.values())

    data_list = str(data_list)
    doc_data = data_list.split()[2][:-4]

    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT born_date, phone_number FROM users.data WHERE email = '%s'" % doc_data.replace("'", ""))
    account = cur.fetchone()

born = account[0]
num = account[1]


    print('Got data:', data)
    return jsonify({
        'status': 'SUCCESS',
        'data': data,
    })


return render_template('profile.html', id=session['id'], born=born, num=num)
```

`html`

```
<select id='sel' name='sel' class="selectpicker sel" multiple data-live-search="true" onchange="optionClick(this)">
    {% for descr in description%}
        <option id="val" value="{{descr}}">{{ descr }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="process();">
    Process
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle" style='font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 18px;'>Information about user</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="form-control" id="mySelectedValue" style="margin-top: 10px;"></p>


        <h2 class="white-text" style="font-size: 14px; color: #000;">Born date is: {{ born }}</h2>
        <h2 class="white-text" style="font-size: 14px; color: #000;">Phone number is: {{ num }}</h2>


        <button class="btn btn-primary">
            Send Data
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
    


<script type="text/javascript">
function printValue(selectedItem) {
    $('#mySelectedValue').html(selectedItem.value.replace(/[{()}]/g, '').replace(/['"]+/g, '').replace(/[{,}]/g, ''));
    console.log(typeof(selectedItem.value));
}
function process(selectedItem) {
    $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show')
    document.getElementById('#exampleModalCenter')
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        "selectedItems": $('#sel').val()
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/profile",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
    });
}
function optionClick(selectedItem) {
    printValue(selectedItem);
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's a little difficult to follow your logic as to what the final value of `doc_data` is after replacement (it would be nice to know). Anyway, 1. You don't show what the error you are getting, if any or if you just end up with an erroneous email value from faulty editing and 2. You are leaving yourself open to a Sql Injection attack. You should instead do: `cur.execute("SELECT born_date, phone_number FROM users.data WHERE email = %s", (email_address,))`. Note there is no quotes around `%s`.

Comment: @Booboo I don’t get any error. I just can not get born_date and phone_number. There’s no error

Comment: Log what you think is the email address you think you are using as the argument and heed my warning above about a SQL Injection attack exposure. Do you follow the above *prepared statement` methodology I used in the above comment?

Comment: @Booboo, Sorry, I can not understand how can I solve this problem

Comment: You are doing `doc_data = data_list.split()[2][:-4]` and then `doc_data.replace("'", "")` and the final results are what you are using as the email address argument for your SQL query, right?. In other words, `email_address = data_list.split()[2][:-4].replace("'", "")`. If you were to write `email_address` out to a file for debugging purposes, what would the value be? Probably not what you expected. When you create a select option value, the value should be the email address *only* and you can display anything you want with it. In that way, no processing of the input is required. (...more)

Comment: For example, `<option value="john_doe@gmail.com">John Doe john_doe@gmail.com</option>`. So, don't code  `{{descr}}` as  the `value`, but rather `{{descr['email']}}.` Then you can get the email address from the input more easily.

Comment: @Booboo. I wrote `email_address = data_list.split()[2][:-4].replace("'", "")` because I get my email with brackets and quotes and by this way I can remove them

Comment: @Booboo. could you help me with code?

Comment: I am retired and tired. But continue to post specific questions after you have made an attempt at your own solution and I or someone else will only be too happy to help. You got your email that way because of the way you wrote your select option, which needlessly contained far more than just the email address. This is what I have  been trying to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Without your printing out what your actual argument is for the email address I can't be sure what the error is, but since you are not getting an exception I can only guess you are using a value that does not exist on the database and hence you are not separating the email address out correctly from the input using what amounts to:

```
email_address = data_list.split()[2][:-4].replace("'", "")
```

So my suggestion is to make the following changes:

In the HTML:

Change `value="{{descr}}">` to `value="{{descr['email']}}">`:

```
<select id='sel' name='sel' class="selectpicker sel" multiple data-live-search="true" onchange="optionClick(this)">
    {% for descr in description%}
        <option id="val" value="{{descr['email']}}">{{ descr }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

In that way only the email address is going to be sent back up when the Ajax call is made.

Your Python code then becomes:

```
data = request.json
email_address = data['selectedItems'][0] # the first email address selected
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT born_date, phone_number FROM users.data WHERE email = %s", (email_address,))
account = cur.fetchone()
```

I believe because you have a multi select dropdown that you will be sent up a list of values even if the list only contains a single item and that's why I have specified `data['selectedItems'][0]`. Of course, the obvious question is if the user has selected multiple email addresses, your code does not seem to handle this, so I don't know why you have made this a multi select dropdown. Note also that I am using a `prepared statement` so SQL Injection attacks should no longer be a problem.

Comment: Did this help at all?

Comment: it did not help(